# How would I display all rows in a CSV in pycharm?

Tags: python, pandas

So far I have

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Serial.csv")
print(data)
```

I have tried

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', see.shape[0]+1)
```

and it still only displays a few rows.

Comment: Where does your `see` variable come from?

Comment: That is a mistype, I meant to type set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in PyCharm.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':list(range(500))})

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0])

print(df)
```